# Useing jmeter-plugins-webdriver with java code , there is a NoClassDefFoundError of ExpectedConditions?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter-plugins

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLtjd.png)

jmeter `version 5.3`

jmeter-plugins-webdriver `version 3.3`

and i found in jmeter-plugins-webdriver.jar's pom

`<selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>`

in this version contains `ExpectedConditions` class [3.141.59-driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk7Ss.png)

here is my code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.UUID;

        WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
        final String targetStory = "story";
        final String token = "11111";

        final String defectContentString = "story$" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(9);
        WDS.log.info("We Start To Test");

            WDS.browser.get("http://localhost:9090/#/agile/work-list/backlog?" +
                    "type=project&id=59&name=%E8%87%AA%E5%8A%A8%E5%8C%96%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AE&category=GENERAL&" +
                    "organizationId=1&redirectFlag");

            WDS.log.info("Wait to Load");

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, Duration.ofSeconds(30).getSeconds());
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".sprintIssueItem")));


        WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

somebody can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have at least the following libraries under "lib" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
selenium-api-3.14.0.jar
selenium-chrome-driver-3.14.0.jar
selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar
selenium-ie-driver-3.14.0.jar
selenium-java-3.14.0.jar
selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar
selenium-support-3.14.0.jar
```

Adding jmeter-plugins-webdriver-xxx.jar to "lib/ext" folder is not sufficient because this way you don't have all the [dependencies](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html) as it gives you only WebDriver Sampler and configuration elements but doesn't provide required [Selenium Java client libraries](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/selenium_installation/installing_selenium_libraries/)

The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins (and eventually keeping them up-to-date) is [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) which will give you not only the JMeter Plugin but also download all the necessary .jars

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i do install webdriver from plugins Manager